# Regular expression string compare ignoring symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, string, equality

I have two variables:

```
varAdditionalTeamAddress = ;; MountainWestITSupport@somedomain.com

VariableAddTeamEmails =  ; MountainWestITSupport@somedomain.com;
```

These two variables are being used to concatenate and collect additional support team emails. But in the process of concatenation, if the emails are empty, only the semicolons come over.

I need to compare these two variables (ignoring the ;) to see if they are equal. Can we write a regular expression to extract all semicolons and spaces from this email string so they are comparable?

Like for the above, had I cleaned them up by excluding the spaces and semicolons, the equality test would have returned TRUE.

Regex gurus, please help. PS I need REGEX way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
varAdditionalTeamAddress = varAdditionalTeamAddress.replace(/^[ ;]+/, "");

VariableAddTeamEmails = VariableAddTeamEmails.replace(/^[ ;]+/, "");
```

to remove any combination of `;` and space from start of your variables.

Comment: I am vegetarian ;)  I would love to learn to fish for other hungry people though! :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for compressed code :

```
if( 
     VariableAddTeamEmails.match( /\w+@\w+\.\w+/g ).indexOf( 
          varAdditionalTeamAddress.match( /\w+@\w+\.\w+/g )[ 0 ] )  
     ) != -1
){
 // ...
}
```

My regexp isn't exactly the best way to get address mail. There are many subjects on it on StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows using PowerShell then you can do this

```
$varAdditionalTeamAddress = ";; MountainWestITSupport@somedomain.com"
$VariableAddTeamEmails = " ; MountainWestITSupport@somedomain.com;"

if ( ($varAdditionalTeamAddress.Trim() -replace '(;+|\s)','') -eq ($VariableAddTeamEmails.Trim() -replace '(;+|\s)','')){
    Write "Email Strings are equal"
}else{
    Write "They Seem to different"
}
```